# Why does my original dataframe change as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the dataset that I am using, it is available on Kaggle at this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/so-survey-2017)

I am doing this to it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./survey_results_public.csv')

df = df.dropna(subset=['Salary'], axis = 0).drop(['Respondent','ExpectedSalary','Salary'], axis = 1)

print(df['HoursPerWeek'].mean())
print(sum(df['HoursPerWeek'].isnull()))

# Method 1
df1 = df
df1 = df1.select_dtypes(include=['float']).fillna(df1.mean())

print(df['HoursPerWeek'].mean())
print(sum(df['HoursPerWeek'].isnull()))
print(df1['HoursPerWeek'].mean())
print(sum(df1['HoursPerWeek'].isnull()))


# Method 2
df2 = df
num_vars = df2.select_dtypes(include = ['float']).columns
for col in num_vars:
    df2[col].fillna(df2[col].mean(),inplace = True)

print(df['HoursPerWeek'].mean())
print(sum(df['HoursPerWeek'].isnull()))
print(df2['HoursPerWeek'].mean())
print(sum(df2['HoursPerWeek'].isnull()))
```

My question is: Why does "Method 2" change df as well, as observed in the last 4 print statements where the mean and number of empty values is the dame between df and df2?

When I do something similar with normal variables in python this does not happen

```
a=2
b=a
c=a

print(a,b,c)

b += 2

print(a,b,c)

c += 3

print(a,b,c)
```

In this example, a is unchanged.

Comment: You should read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want to do is copy the dataframes:

```
...
# Method 1
df1 = df.copy()
df1 = df1.select_dtypes(include=['float']).fillna(df1.mean())
....
# Method 2
df2 = df.copy()
num_vars = df2.select_dtypes(include = ['float']).columns
...
```

Hope this helps :D

A good example are lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a.append(4)
print("b is",b)
# output is 'b is [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Makes sense and I will check out the blog post. Do you happen to know why "Method 1" did not change the original DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, 
the`df1.select_dtypes(include=['float']).fillna(df1.mean())` function already returns a copy of the dataframe. Therefore not changing the original (wich linked to df).

In contrast to that, the second method
`df2[col].fillna(df2[col].mean(),inplace = True)`
includes the `inplace=True` arguement which states NOT to create a copy but replacing the actual entries of the dataframe wich are the entries of the original `df` dataframe

Comment: **no** python has no concept of "primitive" and "non-primitive" types

Comment: Yes, python does not have the concept of primitves and non-primitives. But nevertheless, I think this concept helps to understand the problem stated in the challenge.
I will edit the Answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your contributions. You have helped me further my understanding.